# Is there is Limition of using opencsv API or Apache Poi Api?

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi

I am creating Excel file on the basis of CSV file.for reading CSV file,i am using Opencsv API and Apache POI.In my csv contain 65537 row.

```
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("SampleData.csv"));
    String[] line;
    int r = 0;int count=0;
    while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow((short) r++);
        count=count+1;
         System.out.println("count-"+count);
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++)
            row.createCell(i)
               .setCellValue(helper.createRichTextString(line[i]));
    }

    // Write the output to a file
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}}
```

when i run this program it give me following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid row number (-32768) outside allowable range (0..65535)at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.setRowNum(HSSFRow.java:232)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.<init>(HSSFRow.java:86)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.<init>(HSSFRow.java:70)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.createRow(HSSFSheet.java:205)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.createRow(HSSFSheet.java:71)
    at com.arosys.utilityclasses.Test.main(Test.java:23)Java Result: 1
```

I tried to trace how much row it support i found it only support 32768 and also tried for less number of row,it works nicely and create excel file.

please help me to sort out this problem,if my csv contain 65536 row then how i am bale to write excel file(Xls).

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you casting the row num to short in the following line

```
 Row row = sheet.createRow((short) r++);
```

Leave it as int

Comment: Thanks.i have one more question for u if number of row increases 65536 it able to write file(XLS),on other side for XLXS,how much row i can write using this API.

Comment: Well I'm not sure. you will just have to try it and see. As far as excel versions go, i think the earlier versions of excel(before 2007) were limited to 65536 rows. However the newer version have a much large limit.  1,048,576 is what i can see here http://www.contextures.com/xlfaqapp.html#MoreRows  .So test the output file to see if the version of excel can handle it

Comment: If you want to use more than 65536 rows, you'll need to switch to the .xlsx format, which means changing from HSSF to XSSF

Comment: You're a genious, now I managed to found the cause of a problem in my legacy app

Comment: I had the same error in my code. That's the problem with copy/pasting code from the library tutorials. that "short" cast was in there for some unnecessary reason.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's your short value. the max value on a short is 32767 and you're trying to access one more than that.